# Optimal DB query for prefix search

Tags: mysql, algorithm, mongodb, tree, prefix

I have a dataset which is a list of prefix ranges, and the prefixes aren't all the same size.  Here are a few examples:

```
low: 54661601   high: 54661679   "bin": a
low: 526219100  high: 526219199  "bin": b
low: 4305870404 high: 4305870404 "bin": c
```

I want to look up which "bin" corresponds to a particular value with the corresponding prefix.  For example, value `5466160179125211` would correspond to "bin" a.  In the case of overlaps (of which there are few), we could return either the longest prefix or all prefixes.

The optimal algorithm is clearly some sort of tree into which the bin objects could be inserted, where each successive level of the tree represents more and more of the prefix.

The question is: how do we implement this (in one query) in a database?  It is permissible to alter/add to the data set.  What would be the best data & query design for this?  An answer using mongo or MySQL would be best.

Answer (score 4):

If you make a mild assumption about the number of overlaps in your prefix ranges, it is possible to do what you want optimally using either MongoDB or MySQL. In my answer below, I'll illustrate with MongoDB, but it should be easy enough to port this answer to MySQL.

First, let's rephrase the problem a bit. When you talk about matching a "prefix range", I believe what you're actually talking about is finding the correct range under a *lexicographic* ordering (intuitively, this is just the natural alphabetic ordering of strings).  For instance, the set of numbers whose prefix matches 54661601 to 54661679 is exactly the set of numbers which, when written as strings, are lexicographically greater than or equal to "54661601", but lexicographically less than "54661680".  So the first thing you should do is add 1 to all your **high** bounds, so that you can express your queries this way.  In mongo, your documents would look something like

```
{low: "54661601", high: "54661680", bin: "a"}
{low: "526219100",  high: "526219200",  bin: "b"}
{low: "4305870404", high: "4305870405", bin: "c"}
```

Now the problem becomes: given a set of one-dimensional intervals of the form [**low**, **high**), how can we quickly find which interval(s) contain a given point?  The easiest way to do this is with an index on either the **low** or **high** field. Let's use the **high** field.  In the mongo shell:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({high : 1})
```

For now, let's assume that the intervals don't overlap at all.  If this is the case, then for a given query point "x", the only possible interval containing "x" is the one with the smallest **high** value greater than "x". So we can query for that document and check if its **low** value is also less than "x".  For instance, this will print out the matching interval, if there is one:

```
db.coll.find({high : {'$gt' : "5466160179125211"}}).sort({high : 1}).limit(1).forEach(
       function(doc){ if (doc.low <= "5466160179125211") printjson(doc) } 
  )
```

Suppose now that instead of assuming the intervals don't overlap at all, you assume that every interval overlaps with less than *k* neighboring intervals (I don't know what value of *k* would make this true for you, but hopefully it's a small one).  In that case, you can just replace 1 with *k* in the "limit" above, i.e.

```
 db.coll.find({high : {'$gt' : "5466160179125211"}}).sort({high : 1}).limit(k).forEach(
       function(doc){ if (doc.low <= "5466160179125211") printjson(doc) } 
  )
```

What's the running time of this algorithm?  The indexes are stored using B-trees, so if there are *n* intervals in your data set, it takes O(log *n*) time to lookup the first matching document by **high** value, then O(*k*) time to iterate over the next *k* documents, for a total of O(log *n*  +  *k*) time.  If *k* is constant, or in fact anything less than O(log *n*), then this is asymptotically optimal (this is in the standard model of computation; I'm not counting number of external memory transfers or anything fancy).

The only case where this breaks down is when *k* is large, for instance if some large interval contains nearly all the other intervals.  In this case, the running time is O(*n*).  If your data is structured like this, then you'll probably want to use a different method.  One approach is to use mongo's "2d" indexing, with your **low** and **high** values codifying *x* and *y* coordinates. Then your queries would correspond to querying for points in a given region of the *x* - *y* plane.  This might do well in practice, although with the current implementation of 2d indexing, the worst case is still O(n).

There are a number of theoretical results that achieve O(log *n*) performance for all values of *k*.  They go by names such as Priority Search Trees, Segment trees, Interval Trees, etc. However, these are special-purpose data structures that you would have to implement yourself.  As far as I know, no popular database currently implements them.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you may have to use a stored procedure, which you call to map value to bin.  Said procedure would query the list of buckets for each row and do arithmetic or string ops to find the matching bucket.  You could improve this design by using fixed length prefixes, arranged in a fixed number of layers.  You could assign a fixed depth to your tree and each layer has a table.  You won't get tree-like performance with either of these approaches.

If you want to do something more sophisticated, I suspect you have to use a different platform.

Sql Server has a Hierarchy data type:
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

PostgreSQL has a cidr data type.  I'm not familiar with the level of query support it has, but in theory you could build a routing table inside of your db and use that to assign buckets:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-CIDR

Answer (score 0):

"Optimal" can mean different things to different people.  It seems that you could do something like save your low and high values as varchars.  Then all you have to do is

```
select bin from datatable where '5466160179125211' between low and high
```

Or if you had some reason to keep the values as integers in the table, you could do the CASTing in the query.

I have no idea whether this would give you terrible performance with a large dataset.  And I hope I understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Peyton! :)

If you need to keep everything as integers, and want it to work with a single query, this should work:

```
select bin from datatable where 5466160179125211 between 
      low*pow(10, floor(log10(5466160179125211))-floor(log10(low))) 
   and ((high+1)*pow(10, floor(log10(5466160179125211))-floor(log10(high)))-1);
```

In this case, it would search between the numbers 5466160100000000 (the lowest number with the low prefix & the same number of digits as the number to find) and 546616799999999 (the highest number with the high prefix & the same number of digits as the number to find). This should still work in cases where the high prefix has more digits than the low prefix. It should also work (I think) in cases where the number is shorter than the length of the prefixes, where the varchar code in the previous solution can give incorrect results.

You'll want to experiment to compare the performance of having a lot of inline math in the query (as in this solution) vs. the performance of using varchars.

Edit: Performance seems to be really good either way even on big tables with no indexes; if you can use varchars then you might be able to further boost performance by indexing the low and high columns. Note that you'd definitely want to use varchars if any of the prefixes have initial zeroes. Here's a fix to allow for the case where the number is shorter than the prefix when using varchars:

```
select * from datatable2 where '5466' between low and high
    and length('5466') >= length(high);
```